# NCrunch Failing to Build Project with PostSharp dependency

Tags: postsharp, ncrunch

The "PostSharp.MSBuild.PostSharp30ExtractTools" task could not be loaded from the assembly

Answer (score 3):

http://www.ncrunch.net/documentation/considerations-and-constraints_implicit-file-dependencies

VisualStudio -> NCRUNCH -> Configuration: "Additional files to include" : "....\packages\Postsharp.4.1.20\tools*.*